# Slow count while inner joining tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, database-performance

I'm using postgres 9.4. I've ran `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`. But queries on `inner join` are still slow.

For minimal example, I have 3 tables: `numbersale`, `base_number` and `numberstorethrough`. `number_id` in `numbersale` and `numberstorethrough` are just FKs (`numbersale.number_id` points to `base_number`, `numberstorethrough.number_id` points to `numbersale`, yeah, it's horrible naming):

```
                                                           Table "public.numbersale"
        Column        |           Type           |                           Modifiers                           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                   | integer                  | not null default nextval('numbersale_id_seq'::regclass)       | plain    |              | 
 number_id            | integer                  | not null                                                      | plain    |              | 


                                                        Table "public.base_number"
   Column    |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                  | not null default nextval('base_number_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 


                                                        Table "public.numberstorethrough"
    Column    |           Type           |                               Modifiers                               | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('numberstorethrough_id_seq'::regclass)       | plain   |              | 
 number_id    | integer                  | not null                                                              | plain   |              |
```

Which contains from 250k to 595k entries:

```
$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbersale;
 count  
--------
 258552
(1 row)

Time: 17,845 ms

$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base_number;
 count  
--------
 332484
(1 row)

Time: 16,273 ms

$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numberstorethrough;
 count  
--------
 595812
(1 row)

Time: 56,710 ms
```

And tables have corresponding indices:

```
$ select * from pg_indexes where tablename = 'numbersale';
 schemaname |    tablename     |                 indexname                  | tablespace |                                                              indexdef                                                              
------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
public      | numbersale       | numbersale_number_id_key             |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX numbersale_number_id_key ON numbersale USING btree (number_id)


$ select * from pg_indexes where tablename = 'numberstorethrough';
 schemaname |        tablename         |               indexname               | tablespace |                                                               indexdef                                                               
------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | numberstorethrough       | numberstorethrough_number_id    |            | CREATE INDEX numberstorethrough_number_id ON numberstorethrough USING btree (number_id)
```

And my problem is the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "numbersale"
INNER JOIN "base_number"
   ON ( "numbersale"."number_id" = "base_number"."id" )
INNER JOIN "numberstorethrough"
  ON ( "numbersale"."id" = "numberstorethrough"."number_id" );
 count  
 --------
 595812
(1 row)

Time: 541,523 ms
```

Explain for that query:

```
Aggregate  (cost=62564.67..62564.68 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=34443.31..61075.14 rows=595812 width=0)
        Hash Cond: (numberstorethrough.number_id = numbersale.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on numberstorethrough  (cost=0.00..10539.12 rows=595812 width=4)
        ->  Hash  (cost=30201.41..30201.41 rows=258552 width=4)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=14411.42..30201.41 rows=258552 width=4)
                    Hash Cond: (base_number.id = numbersale.number_id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on base_number  (cost=0.00..7102.84 rows=332484 width=4)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=10169.52..10169.52 rows=258552 width=8)
                          ->  Seq Scan on numbersale  (cost=0.00..10169.52 rows=258552 width=8)
```

Is it normal, that such basic query with two inner joins takes more than half-second (sometimes it takes up to 700ms)? And rows counts is not even millions, it's just 300-600k.

I've simplified my query, in practice it's larger and takes more than 1 second, but problem with joins is my main bottleneck.

Comment: Your first join condition is not correct because `"number"` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to adapt names, but made some typos. `number` should be `base_number`. I'm very sorry for this inconvenience!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT...` often performs much worse than you might expect. Do you *really* need the count of rows, or are you just trying to determine if there are any rows matching the query conditions? If you do a `SELECT *...` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)...`, what happens to the performance? Your query is doing a sequential scan on all three of the tables - in my opinion the amazing thing is not that it takes 500 to 700 ms, but that it **ONLY** takes 500 to 700 ms. YMMV.

Comment: @BobJarvis just tried only `SELECT *` with `explain analyze`. No gain to performance. I don't really need exact count for all this rows, it's my pagination behavior -- maybe, I should find out some workaround.

I wonder, why indices don't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the joins produce an intermediate result that is very large, but is then filtered out by the second join.  This still doesn't explain why the indexes are not being used, but perhaps this might have better performance:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "base_number" bn
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "numbersale" ns WHERE ns."number_id" = bn."id") AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "numberstorethrough" nst WHERE bn."id" = nst."number_id");
```

You already have the correct indexes for this (and your original) query:  `numbersale(number_id)`, `base_number(id)` and `numberstorethrough(number_id)`.

Comment: But I already have indices. See my output from `pg_indexes`-table.

Comment: @prokaktus . . . I greatly modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But my `number_id` field in `numberstorethrough` points to `numbersale`, not `base_number`. It's a little horrible naming, unfortunately. And my `numberstorethrough` is m2m-table, which can contain more than one `number_id`. Because of that `select` with `exists` provide not the same functionality.

I'll edit answer to make this more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

My best interpretation of the query plan is that the indexes aren't used because there's nothing in the query which limits the rows which should be fetched. Every row in each of the tables is being read. So what good would using an index in this situation be? The database would have to spend time reading the index, and then would still have to read the 'real' data. No gain. If there was a WHERE clause which limited what the query was pulling back, or if the join conditions did something to limit the number of rows retrieved I expect that the indexes might come into play. Indexes are not magic - their use is not automatically 'better', and their absence from a query plan is not automatically 'worse'. As with many things, it depends :-) - and in this case it appears that the use of an index or indexes would be a net loss from the point of view of the query optimizer. Also keep in mind that `COUNT` is not magical - it's a function which simply counts the number of rows in a result set. It doesn't magically "know" how many rows are projected to be in a result set - the database has to PRODUCE the result set, and then `COUNT` just counts up how many rows there are.

Comment: It's OK, that sometimes database don't use indexes, but in my case reading with joins 10x times slower than reading most larger table at alone. I don't expect magic, but such performance difference looks very daunting for me. But anyway, thanks for your time and answer!